# Polig-helman - solving $3^x = 5 \pmod{113}$ - 2 methods give different values for $x_1$ for $40^x=42$

Tags: congruences, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I am using the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm to solve a [*Discrete
Log Problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) to
find $x$ in

$$3^x = 5 \pmod{113}$$

Using the notation:

$$g^x = h \pmod p$$

We have

$g = 3$, $h = 5$, $p = 113$,

$N = p - 1 = 112 = \prod_{i=1}^{n} q_i^{e_i} = q_1^{e_1}
\cdot q_2^{e_2} = 2^4 \cdot 7^1 $

We can summarize the necessary algorithm calculations in a handy table as

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
  \large q  & \large e & \large g^{(p-1)/q^e} & \large h^{(p-1)/q^e} &
\mbox{Solve}~ \large \left(g^{(p-1)/q^e} \right)^x = ~ \large
h^{(p-1)/q^e}~ \mbox{for} ~ \large x \\  \hline
2 & 4 & 40 & 42 & \mbox{Calculation I = ?}\\
   \hline
7 & 1 & ... & ... & \mbox{...}\\  \hline
\end{array}$$

**I am only interested in $q=2$ and $e=4$ for this question.**

**Calculation I:**

Solve

$$x \equiv x_0 + x_1q + \ldots + x_{e-1}q^{e−1} \pmod {2^4} \equiv
x_0 + 2x_1 + 4x_2 + 8x_3 \pmod {2^4}$$

- Solve $(40)^x = 42 \pmod {113}$ for $x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3$.

**Method 1 - J. Hoffstein, J Piper, J. H. Silverman**

- $x_0: (40^{2^3})^{x_0} = 112^{x_0} = 42^{2^3} = 112 \pmod {113} \implies (112)^{x_0}
  = 112 \pmod{113} \implies x_0 = 1$
- $x_1: (40^{2^3})^{x_1} = 112^{x_1} = (42 \times 40^{-x_0})^{2^2} \pmod {113} \implies (112)^{x_1} = 112 \pmod{113} \implies x_1 = 1$
- Continuing this method I find $x_2=0$ and $x_3=0$.

**Method 2 - $\frac{p-1}{q}$**

https://youtu.be/BXFNYVmdtJU
https://www.cryptologie.net/article/196/pohlig-hellman-algorithm/

$\beta = 42$, $\alpha=40$.

- $x_0: q=2^1, \beta^{\frac{p-1}{q}}=\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{q}x_0}. \implies x_0=1$.
- $x_1: q=2^2, \beta_1^=\beta \times \alpha^{-x_0}.\implies \beta_1=18.  \implies \beta_1^{\frac{p-1}{q}}=\alpha^{\frac{p-1}{q}x_1}. \implies x_1=2$.
- Continuing this with this method I find $x_2=0$ and $x_3=0$.

**Hence for Method 1 I get $(x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3)=(1, 1, 0, 0)$ but for Method 2 I get $(1, 2, 0, 0)$**

I'm struggling to see where I'm going wrong in my working re $x_1$.

Comment: $3$ is a primitive root modulo $113$ and $3^{83}=5$ modulo $113$.

Comment: @piquito. That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @moo updated question with links

Comment: @unseen_rider: I know. It was a simple comment ( from FLT $3^{56}=-1$ and $3^{27}=-5$ give the exponent $83=56+27$)

Comment: @piquito. Ok and how do you get the 56 and 27? I understand FLT, but not how you got there. Also any ideas on my question please?

Comment: This class of calculations can be given in multiple ways according to the inspiration or intuition of each one. By $3^{112}=1$ we have $3^{56} = \pm 1$ and can not be +1 (why?). As for $3^{27}=-5$ comes from $3^5=17$ by successives easy multiplications. Concerning properly your question I do not know Polig-Helman. I am sorry.